# Implement and/or tree in python

Tags: python, tree

I need to implement an And/or tree in python so I can evaluate boolean expressions, 
I had an idea of creating a class that contains `andNode`, `orNode` and `leafNode`. The first two are are internal nodes that must have and or or values, the `leafNode` must have and integer value and represent the final leaves of the tree.I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self,leaf):
     self.orNode = None
     self.andNode = None
     self.leaf = leaf

class and_or_tree (Node):
   def __init__(self):
       self.root=None
```

I need to test if an element exists in the tree, the height and iterate through it.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. "doesn't seems to work" is **never** a good diagnoses. What's happening ? Is there an error message ? Or an unexpected result ? Please **edit** your question to precise how it doesn't work.

Comment: I mean I don't know how to add elements or how to use it, I am new in python and I want to use this structure since I think it is the best one to store big boolean expressions in a compact way.

Comment: "I don't know how to add elements or how to use it". Did you try something ? Then please show us your attempt and why they failed. We won't write code for you. We are here to help but not to do you work for you.

Comment: I don't need codes, I need explanations, it seems that I can only add integer values. I have created tow methods to add and insert elements
when I try to add andNodes or orNodes it accept only integers not 'and' or 'or' values.( I don't know how to add further codes as comments)

Comment: Right now your question is much too broad to get an answer which is not 10 page long. "it seems that I can only add integer values". Then you tried something which failed. Show that to us and we will help to fix it.

Comment: ` def addNode(self,leaf):
        
        return Node(leaf)
    
    def insert(self,root,leaf):
        if(root == None):
            root = self.addNode(leaf)
        else:
            if(leaf <= root.leaf):
               root.andNode = self.insert(root.andNode,leaf)
            else:
                root.orNode = self.insert(root.orNode,leaf)
        return root `

Answer (score 3):

I think an example of such Leaf and and/or nodes could be something like this:

```
class Leaf: 
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.val = v;   

    def __call__(self): 
        return self.val 


class AndNode:
    def __init__(self, l, r):
        self.left = l; 
        self.right = r; 

    def __call__(self): 
        return self.left() and self.right() 



class OrNode: 
    def __init__(self, l, r):
        self.left = l; 
        self.right = r; 

    def __call__(self): 
        return self.left() or self.right()
```

You can build a tree like this:

```
print AndNode(Leaf(True), Leaf(False))()  
print AndNode(OrNode(Leaf(True), Leaf(False)), Leaf(True))()
```

Which outputs this:

```
False
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works perfectly! the leaf class accepts my integer values and I have the expressions right. I can move on in peace lol.